# cannot ping www.google in a docker container when connected to one wifi

Tags: macos, docker

For some strange reason, I am not able to ping www.google.com when connected to one wifi.

If I disconnect from that wifi and connect to another wifi, I am able to ping www.google.com.   This has happened on 2 different wifi.
While on those wifi networks, I am able to browse the web and ssh into AWS ec2.

```
------ On good wifi, my t-mobile hotspot ----
Joshuas-MBP:react-tutorial joshuacalloway$ docker run alpine ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.216.68): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 216.58.216.68: seq=0 ttl=61 time=34.701 ms


----- On 2 different wifi networks, iphone 6 t-mobile hotspot and a company guest wifi network ----
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 29.912/52.059/91.565 ms
Joshuas-MBP:react-tutorial joshuacalloway$ docker run alpine ping www.google.com
ping: bad address 'www.google.com'
```

---

docker -v
Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd

On mac os X 10.11.3

Comment: Does ping on the bad wifi work inside your boot2docker virtual but not inside a container?

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to ping the IP while switching between WiFi? If you can ping the IP, then I would try one of two solutions:

1. Edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` from the host in order to use external DNS (e.g., 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4)
2. Run docker with `-dns` option, e.g.,

   ```
   docker run -dns 8.8.8.8 -dns 8.8.4.4 base ping google.com
   ```

Or reboot the default virtualbox container:

```
docker-machine restart default
```

Comment: a restart of docker-machine seems to have fixed the issue. will continue to keep thread updated as I find out more